# How to implement a button on the left side of the header in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have a main Stack navigator(X) and inside that I have screen which takes me to another stack navigator(A). But when I go stack(A) it's not showing me the button to go back to stack(X). I do understand that using multiple stack navigators like these is not the best practice, but I want to implement a Tab navigator inside of stack(A) and each of the tabs would contain a stack navigator.

I have tried implementing a button as described [on the react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/), but it doesn't describe how to implement it on the left side of the header.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same code provided in the docs only change is that instead of headerRight you have to use [headerLeft](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headerleft) but this will also change the back behavior, check the docs for more details.

```
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
              title="Info"
              color="#fff"
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
```